# UI Automation monitoring

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, monitoring, ui-automation

I'm trying to monitor an external WPF application(no source-code) from a local app, and see when a button is clicked in c#.

So far i've been exploring UI Automation's options, and i saw that it works similar if not same to the Inspect.exe tool.

The problem i have is, the WPF form i need to monitor **does not** contain the button i need directly, as a sub-control. Instead, first you need to log in, then click a few buttons and then finally a new window opens, and it contains the button i need to check.

So my question is, is there a way this to be monitored with the UI Automation? I know i can trigger an event when the main form starts a new process, and the button is clicked, but how do i handle all the steps in between?

(Or in other words how can i trigger an event when the final window containing the button i need to check is actually open)

Comment: With an `Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent, (...)`, you can detect any Window creation in the System. You need to know some details of the Window you are watching to tell it apart. A Window Title, a Class Name or anything else that allows to single it out. The `Process.Id` will be the same as the parent Window (the Main Process), but the UI Element class and its `NativeWindowHandle` will not. This, of course, depends on what the main application is doing. It could also start a new Process, but you just need to know what to look for.

Comment: You are the best @Jimi :)